# Is there a way to get full IntelliSense for VBA in Access and Excel 2007?

Tags: vba, intellisense

In VB.NET, the IntelliSense pops up as soon as you start typing which gives you a pretty full list of things you can use at that moment. The IntelliSense in *VBA* however, doesn't kick on for me until a period is put after the part you're using. For example, I go into the VBA editor in Excel 2007 and start typing the word "`Range`" but the IntelliSense doesn't come up until I type "`Range.`" after which it will give me a list of things I can use at that point.

Is there any way to make IntelliSense come up sooner in the VBA editor, so that I'm able to see a list of things that can be used like `Davg`, `DCount`, etc?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, but you can type `Excel` first.  Put a period after that, and you'll find out more than you ever wanted to know about Excel.

Same with Access.  Type `Access` and a period, and you will find `DCount` there.

Answer (score 30):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> at any time in the editor.

Comment: You have changed my life forever. I am elated and depressed at the same time. I have cumulatively wasted years of my life not knowing this.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately in Excel some objects are declared 'As Object' and Object doesn't have any methods so Intellisense won't be able to display any.  The main culprit being Excel.ActiveSheet.

If you know what the type actually is then you can declare it explicitly and assign it to the value you want.  EG:

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = ActiveSheet     'This line would cause a type mismatch error if mySheet was declared as something other than a WorkSheet
mysheet.[All The Intellisense For a Worksheet Pops Up]
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet` could also be a `Chart`: in that case you'd get a type mismatch if `mySheet` had been declared as Worksheet. That's why ActiveSheet is of type "object": it's not always going to be a WorkSheet...

Comment: I'm also assuming this applies to `ThisWorkbook`. Is that true?

Comment: @Taelsin The `Application.ThisWorkbook` property appears to be strongly typed as `Workbook`, unlike `ActiveSheet` which is typed as `Object`. Also, this doesn't really answer the OP's question; it is an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387950/autocomplete-drop-down-box-for-arguments-past-the-first-full-stop/60388270?noredirect=1#comment106864945_60388270).

Answer (score 3):

VBA is a different beast than .NET so I'm not sure how to bring up the IntelliSense quicker.  I find I have the same problem you're having in 2003.

I would suggest checking out the Object Browser though.  In 2003, it's View > Object Browser, or F2, in the VB Editor.  I find it's a great way to explore the class libraries available.  It will show you everything that you currently have referenced and once you reference more libraries, they will also show up in the Object Browser.