# Is there an auto complete shortcut in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty sure there is an auto complete feature in the Excel/VBA editor but can't seem to find it. (e.g. Ctrl+Space in Eclipse).

Or am I dreaming it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is, and it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

If you press that and auto complete does not happen, then there are multiple possible choices and you are presented with them.

At this point, you can navigate through the options using the arrow keys <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd> and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select your choice.

Also see [Is there a way to get full IntelliSense for VBA in Access and Excel 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065814/11683), which is almost a duplicate.

Comment: But why it inserts a line break once I choose the item I need from the list of completions?

Comment: @Dror Because this is how autocomplete works in VB (all versions). Do not press enter to select, press some other key, e.g. a space or period or an operator such as `+`.

Comment: Seems like `TAB` is the best option