# Looping CountColour

Tags: vba, loops

Some simple code below. I think I'm having trouble with referencing and looping within a loop.

I'd like to count the number of green cells in a row,then move to the next row. I'm getting an error here:

```
If RowRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.colour = SourceColour.DisplayFormat.Interior.colour Then
```

Run-time error 91 - object not set....

Any  ideas?

Full code:

```
Sub countcolourloop1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim RowRange As Range
Dim SourceColour As Range
Dim xBackColour As Integer

'count green cells
Set SourceColour = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("BN2:BN2")

    'cyle through each row, add 1 to the counter xBackColour every time you find a cell in the range matching the SourceColour
    For I = 4 To 300
        Set RowRange = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & I & ":BK" & I)
        If RowRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.colour = SourceColour.DisplayFormat.Interior.colour Then
        xBackColour = xBackColour + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: "rng" is not set.  "ColorRange" is not set.  Why is there "SourceColor"?  What is special about that cell  BN2 ?  Also, good practice would not have hard coded  300 but rather vars like RowMax or ColMax, and would rather compute these based on the contents of the sheet. And would use descriptive var names, like iRow and jCol, to cycle thru the rows/cols.

Comment: Looks like you mistakenly used `rng` instead of `RowRange` and `ColorRange` instead `SourceColour`!

Comment: thanks for the comments; BN2 holds the background colour  I'm trying to count. I've updated the references but still having an error on the same line. Also, do i need a loop to cycle through each cell in the range, or will it handle this naturally?

Comment: @JamesO'Sullivan It's `Interior.Color`, not `colour`. This is the second time your error is caused by a typo! You really need to learn how to [debug your code](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php) and how to use [the IntelliSense](https://i.postimg.cc/FstYnXNS/Interior_Color.png) to avoid such mistakes. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065814/4934172) for more.

Comment: If RowRange...Color tests for ALL the cells being the same one color...  Test your line of code yourself on one or two rows, and see what you get.